# How to parse  Japanese Era Date string values into LocalDate & LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, internationalization, datetime-format

How to parse Japanese era date string inputs into `LocalDate/LocalDateTime` via Java 8 DateTime API?

Example Japanese calendar dates;

```
明治23年11月29日
昭和22年5月3日
平成23年3月11日（金）14時46分
令和5年1月11日
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is achieved by utilizing [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in the following manner;

```
DateTimeFormatter japaneseEraDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("GGGGy年M月d日")
        .withChronology(JapaneseChronology.INSTANCE)
        .withLocale(Locale.JAPAN);
```

where `GGGG` in the pattern is the designator for the Japanese characters representing [the era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_era_name)
(e.g. `平成` [Heisei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisei)), and the rest with year/month/day values with their respective Japanese characters: `y年` for year, `M月` for the month, `d日` for the day.

```
LocalDate.parse("明治23年11月29日", japaneseEraDtf);
LocalDate.parse("昭和22年5月3日", japaneseEraDtf);
LocalDate.parse("令和5年1月11日", japaneseEraDtf);
```

will give out;

```
1890-11-29
1947-05-03
2023-01-11
```

---

For `LocalDateTime`, by using the updated pattern `"GGGGy年M月d日（E）HH時mm分"` in `japaneseEraDtf`;

```
LocalDateTime.parse("平成23年3月11日（金）14時46分", japaneseEraDtf);
```

will result in;

```
2011-03-11T14:46
```