# How to convert Western date to Japanese date in java?

Tags: android, calendar

I have a String of western date.I want is to have it in Japanese format.

```
String date = "2015-06-01";
```

I want is to have it in Japanese format. Please help me!

```
output = 平成27年6月1日
```

Comment: Have you tried date formatter with setting locale?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my lib [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) which is also available for lower Android API levels and then use its [JapaneseCalendar](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/JapaneseCalendar.html):

```
    String input = "2015-06-01";
    PlainDate gregorian = Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_DATE.parse(input);
    ChronoFormatter<JapaneseCalendar> f = // immutable, so you can make it static
        ChronoFormatter.ofStyle(DisplayMode.MEDIUM, Locale.JAPANESE, JapaneseCalendar.axis());
    String output = f.print(gregorian.transform(JapaneseCalendar.axis()));
    System.out.println(output); // 平成27年6月1日
```

I have also done an experiment with the `java.time`-package which is available since API level 26, but could not quickly find a way to produce the format you want:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.JAPAN)
            .withChronology(JapaneseChronology.INSTANCE);
    JapaneseDate japaneseDate = JapaneseDate.from(LocalDate.parse(input));
    System.out.println(dtf.format(japaneseDate)); // H27.06.01
```

The numbers are correct but it does not use Japanese symbols and letters, despite of the fact that I specified the Japan locale. Maybe a workaround using the builder and a hand-made pattern will help further. Note that my experiment was executed in a Java-8-environment. Maybe Android or newer Java versions are different?!

Answer (score 1):

As a minor supplement to the answer by Meno Hochschild, if you want to use java.time for this, you may do it in this way:

```
    DateTimeFormatter japaneseEraDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("GGGGy年M月d日")
            .withChronology(JapaneseChronology.INSTANCE)
            .withLocale(Locale.JAPAN);

    String date = "2015-06-01";
    LocalDate gregorianDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
    JapaneseDate japaneseDate = JapaneseDate.from(gregorianDate);
    System.out.println(japaneseDate.format(japaneseEraDtf));
```

Output is:

> 平成27年6月1日

I think it was what you asked for.

If I have understood correctly, java.time does not format the first year of an era in the way usually expected by Japanese, which Meno Hochschild’s Time4A library does, so all things being equal you will prefer his answer.

I have stolen the formatter from [this answer by buræquete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57174740/5772882).

Comment: Interesting, so `java.time`-solution works pattern-based but not style-based for unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd").withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE)
        .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter japanDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy年MM月dd日")
                .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE)
                .withLocale(Locale.JAPAN);
    }
     System.out.println(localDate.format(dateFormat));
     System.out.println(localDate.format(japanDateFormat));
```

Output is:

2022/06/15

2022年06月15日